# How to directly upload files from browser to Google Cloud in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage

I have a Rails app that allows users to upload files. They currently upload (via POST) to the server, which then uses the fog gem to upload it to Google Cloud Storage. The problem with this is that files are universally available to everyone who knows the URL, which I want to prevent.

So now I have two issues I'd like to solve:

- I'd like to enable users to upload to Google directly from browsers
- I'd like to prevent everyone from downloading files, but users that are logged into my app

I have downloaded the p12 file that Google API generated, but now I'm stuck. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs) I need to generate key (done with google-api-client gem) and signature (not done) and then put those into POST headers if I understood correctly?

Does anyone has an example I could use?

EDIT: Got it done, the secret is in *Interoperable Storage Access Keys* and *SHA1*, which google documentation doesn't say. I'll cover the solution in a blog post shortly.

Comment: I am interested in seeing how you solved this. Have you put together a blog post?

Comment: seconding this. Currently developing an angular app and would like to upload photos directly to google cloud storage.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of [generating signed URLs in Python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python). The details will be different in Ruby, but the process is the same.

Comment: This is only applicable for non-POST requests, so it's not applicable to my first question.